# how to pass service account in AuthorizedSession for authentication without passing or saving service account details

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a cloud function(CF1), which in turn calls http based cloud function(CF2).

For calling CF2, I am using "AuthorizedSession" as given below. Is there a way where we can pass only service account as part of authentication in credential variable?

I don't want to store service account related information, like  service account json file,  anywhere in gcp-project. Below is the example:

```
credentials = service_account.IDTokenCredentials.from_service_account_file(service_account_info_file,
                                                                                    target_audience=base_url)
authed_session = AuthorizedSession(credentials)

req =  { "src_gcs_bucket" : 'bucket1234',
          "source_folder" : 'output',
         "dest_gcs_bucket" : 'bucket_dest',
         "dest_project" : 'projectid'
        }
        
 response = authed_session.post(base_url, json=req, allow_redirects=True)
 print(response.status_code, response.reason)
```

Here:
**base_url**  :  URL for http cloud function
**service_account_info_file** : this variable will store Service account details.

Comment: From what I know, you can try 2 things:  

1. try creating it as an environment variable and use it in your code.
2. add to your config file and import the config file and read it from there.
  
Other suggestions / approaches are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use credentials without storing service account JSON files. To do that, you can access the credentials of the service account CF1 is deployed as.
This small example shows CF1 calling CF2
**CF1 main.py** saved to ./cf1

```
import os, urllib
import google.auth.transport.requests
import google.oauth2.id_token

def cf_demo(request):

    target_url = os.environ["TARGET_URL"]
    
    req = urllib.request.Request(target_url)

    auth_req = google.auth.transport.requests.Request()
    id_token = google.oauth2.id_token.fetch_id_token(auth_req, target_url)

    req.add_header("Authorization", f"Bearer {id_token}")
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req)

    resp = response.read()
    resp = f'back from cf2 - response is {resp}'
    print(resp)
    return resp
```

**CF1 requirements.txt**

```
urllib3
google-auth
requests
```

**CF2 main.py** saved to ./cf2

```
from flask import make_response

def cf_demo(request):

    headers={ 'content-type':'text/plain' }
    response = make_response("hello from cf2",200)
    response.headers = headers
    return response
```

The following commands will deploy and setup the demonstration

```
GCP_REGION='us-east4'
PROJECT_ID='my-project-123'
SRV_ACCOUNT='cf-svc-account'

# create a service account used by both functions
gcloud iam service-accounts create $SRV_ACCOUNT \
    --display-name "Service account for demonstrating cf - cf calls"
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding ${PROJECT_ID} --member \
    serviceAccount:$SRV_ACCOUNT@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role "roles/logging.logWriter"

# deploy CF2 with security 
gcloud functions deploy cf2 \
    --region=$GCP_REGION \
    --runtime=python39 \
    --service-account=$SRV_ACCOUNT@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --source=./cf2 \
    --trigger-http \
    --entry-point=cf_demo \
    --ingress-settings=all \
    --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
    --quiet

$ get CF2 url
TARGET_URL=$(gcloud functions describe cf2 --region us-east4 --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")

gcloud functions add-iam-policy-binding cf2 \
    --member=serviceAccount:$SRV_ACCOUNT@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --role=roles/cloudfunctions.invoker \
    --region=$GCP_REGION

# deploy CF1 with no security
gcloud functions deploy cf1 \
    --region=$GCP_REGION \
    --runtime=python39 \
    --service-account=$SRV_ACCOUNT@${PROJECT_ID}.iam.gserviceaccount.com \
    --set-env-vars=TARGET_URL=$TARGET_URL \
    --source=./cf1 \
    --trigger-http \
    --entry-point=cf_demo \
    --ingress-settings=all \
    --allow-unauthenticated \
    --project=${PROJECT_ID} \
    --quiet

# get CF1 url
CF1_URL=$(gcloud functions describe cf1 --region us-east4 --format="value(httpsTrigger.url)")

curl --request GET $CF1_URL
```

The documentation at this
[Link](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/samples/functions-bearer-token#functions_bearer_token-python) provides code samples of how to invoke an HTTP function GET request

Comment: Thanks for reply. i am trying the implement the same  but getting "401 Unauthorized" even though same service account is assigned to both the cloud function

Comment: I've added one more step, you'll need to grant the service account invoke permissions on CF2

Comment: Thanks for the reply . Service account has "Cloud Functions Invoker" permission

Comment: I've added a link to the recommended method of calling Cloud Functions from Python, I'm not familiar with AuthorizedSession, using urllib() with google.auth.transport.requests works for me

Comment: Also when you say Service account has "Cloud Functions Invoker" permission you will need to see those permissions when looking at the Permissions Tab of CF2

Comment: tried using urlib () , getting HTTP 500 error. can u plz share me the real time  example of this

Comment: I have updated the answer with an end to end example